# How can I actualize my wifi drivers?

Tags: drivers, wireless

{I have an ASUS (X441MA) and mi wifi conection got enable withno reason and the only way to fix it is restarting the computer. I have been told that that might be because of the drivers; so I dowloaded from the web page, but I dont know how to make it run, when ever I try to ruunit a message saying "No se cómo tratar " (I do noot know how to treat) pups up.

Is there any tutorial that I can check in order to fix it my self?}

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2b31]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version? What kind of drivers did you download?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: I went to this web page: https://www.asus.com/co/Laptops/ASUS-Laptop-X441MA/HelpDesk_Download/ and got the driver that said "Others"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I don't see any wireless drivers there.

Comment: what should I do then?

Comment: Please open a terminal window, run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` , copy the result, click [edit], and paste the result into your question, so we can see which WiFi hardware you have. What you found under 'Others' was a BIOS update, not a WiFi driver.

Comment: There are no "installable" drivers for this adapter. It is supported by Linux kernel.

Comment: So the main problem of my computer isnt the driver, right? the only left option is take it to technical support?

Comment: Thank  you , all of you! you are very nice people!

Comment: Yes, I see the wifi icon, right now is working right, but when My wifi stops working an "?" appears in front of it.

Comment: There may be a lot of reasons why wifi stops working that are not related to Ubuntu or hardware at all.

Comment: I know but the computer pops up a meesage that says "Contac your sofware developer" thats why I asked. Any way I will try to take it to some tecnichian. If the problem isnt solved I'll come back and makeanother question. Have a beutiful day.

Comment: In terminal run `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && systemctl restart network-manager.service` see if it works better as the Atheros modules don't care for wifi power management